# Avira free using 1.45GB of memory on Win7, what can i do?

Tags: windows-7, memory, ssd, windows-explorer, anti-virus

I have Windows 7. Resource Monitor says that explorer.exe is using 1.4GB and Avira is using 1.45GB. That's too much ram, I have 4GB total. Including Chrome and other processes I have less than 1GB available for other processes.

Can I reduce this 1.45GB use of Avira?

I have tried disabling Avira and closing avira.exe and my PC still uses 1.2GB. I figure that perhaps I have to install something else.

How can I make my PC use less than 2.8GB for background processes? I have 4GB + SSD and I have only 1GB general free memory on my PC. I am analysing audio files and the arrays crash the compiler very often. Ideas please.

[image: Processes screenshot]

Comment: `Can i reduce this 1.45gb use of Avira?` You can uninstall Avira, which should fix the RAM usage. It is also possible that it's scanning in the background, try to disable these features or check it's control panel. This question might fit better at the Avira helpdesk, we are not "Avira service engineers".

Comment: You told me what i couldn't bring myself to consider, to brave the tedium of 10 minutes of add-remove-download-install-wizard configurations for a program which probably would completely hammer me with nag windows. Your tone spurned me... The processes have now regained their freedom!!!... Are you honestly telling me that you and other members, in the midsts of troubleshooting memory issues, would actually suscribe to various manufacturer forums, like Avira and MSN, to get their captcha and unkown reply quality and emails,  are they going to discourage you to find a better antivirus solution?

Comment: I'm not sure on how I should interpret your comment. But I didn't mean to "spurn" you with my "tone". I haven't downvoted your question nor have I upvoted my comment. So it seems someone agrees with me. I'll try to do my best in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I reduce this 1.45GB use of Avira?

*Forgive me for the (first) obvious solutions, but it's best to list all solutions.*

**Check if it's scanning in the background**

Some anti-virus programs simply don't care about memory management. Nor give you options to reduce memory usage. It might be (secretly) scanning in the background or doing "virusscanner stuff".

**Deinstall Avira**

This will certainly decrease RAM usage :) To be honest, Avira.ServiceHost.exe sounds even a little malacious. Why not just Avira.exe? If there is a software bug in Avira (memory leak) I don't think you could fix it. If anyone knows about this, it would be Avira or their engineers.

`I have tried disabling Avira and closing avira.exe and my PC still uses 1.2GB`
Using only 1.2GB for all other processes isn't that much?

**Maybe this might help?**

1,3GB for explorer.exe is also a little much?
Either Avira is bumping this up (since it's scanning or defragmenting) or you've got some problems with your windows installation.

You can try this:

- Check the web for others having the same problem (and possible solution)
- Boot in safe mode and check if the issue is persistent.
- Check and repair you windows integrity using: sfc /scannow
- If nothing works, reinstall your windows, so you're sure that isn't the problem
- After re-installing windows, clean-install Avira (and if it persists, it's probably their fault, get another Antivirus, you can't just de-allocate RAM I believe, that would also give more errors I guess.)

**ALTERNATIVES:**

**Install linux**

That's one way to fix memory issues and anti-virus issues?

**Consider an RAM upgrade**

4GB isn't that much RAM nowadays. I don't really get why you would have a SSD but only 4GB RAM. I've got a laptop with 8GB of RAM but a regular HDD and it works great. (Since only loading stuff to RAM takes time, opening word/IDE/games)

Comment: Thanks, i just have to upgrade the entire PC with an awesome highly configured windows 7 all new again which is 1000ds of hours... I have changed the antivirus and the resource monitor shows 3gb of memory as being free, and unity3d still crashes when it uses more than 1gb due to lack of memory. am confused.

Comment: Good to hear that a re-install fixed at least a little part of the problem.
You might try: "http://answers.unity3d.com/" since it's a stack-exchange-"like" help site, which is full of enthusiasts and experienced unity users.
How are you so sure it's the lack of memory? Maybe you should check your (videocard) drivers, since you re-installed windows. You might go out of video memory. Also, be sure you got all windows 7 updates.

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be whether you have 32 or 64 bit operating system, 32 bit can't recognise or utilise 4 gig of ram. I just installed Avira and gave up after a night mare day with it never fully installing and acting like a virus itself. 
Don't forget your operating system uses around 2 gig and why not restore your system to an earlier date and use an alternative malware program.

Comment: "32 bit can't recognise or utilise 4 gig of ram" This is only correct for WIndows 7 Starter (limited to 2GB). All other 32-bit Windows editions can use 4GB. [Physical Memory Limits: Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7)